# GCM Google Play Library IllegalArgumentException Service not registered

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, google-play-services

I'm trying to incorporate GCM (Google Cloud Messaging) into my app. Ever since adding the GCM lib into my Android Studio project, I've been getting frequent app crashes at random times with the following log:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzl$zzb$zza@423bc838
        at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:926)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.unbindService(ContextImpl.java:1485)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.unbindService(ContextWrapper.java:508)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.stats.zzb.zza(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzl$zzb.zzcd(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzl.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here are my dependencies in the gradle:

```
dependencies {
compile project(':viewpagerindicator')
compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:1.20.0'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
compile 'com.google.guava:guava:14.0.1'
compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.3'
compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.5.0')

compile files('libs/google-api-client-1.16.0-rc.jar')
compile files('libs/google-api-client-android-1.16.0-rc.jar')
compile files('libs/google-http-client-android-1.16.0-rc.jar')
compile files('libs/greendao-1.3.0-beta-1.jar')
compile files('libs/guice-4.0-beta4-no_aop.jar')
compile files('libs/javax.inject.jar')
compile files('libs/jsr305-1.3.9.jar')
provided "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.12.6"}
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Check out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/17026749/1384010

Comment: In http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17012246/authenticated-cloud-endpoint-intermittent-failure-in-android-client/17026749#17026749, the stack trace clearly shows the exception thrown from a user Activity inside an AsyncTask, so it's possible to put in a catch() there. But in my case, the stack trace is not triggered by my code, so I have no way of catching the exception, as far as I can see.